# When using viewmodel can not convert list to entities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I use viewmodel and in my controller can not convert list to entity.

Here is my viewmodel:

```
namespace SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models
{
    public class DashboardModel
    {
        public Advert allAdvert { get; set; }
        public Advert allAdvert2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Dashboard()
         {
             string email_uzivatele = (String)Session["email"];
             DashboardModel adverts = new DashboardModel();

             List<Advert> time = AdvertServiceLayer.Instance.SelectAllWith(email_uzivatele, "Reklama na určitou dobu");
             List<Advert> price = AdvertServiceLayer.Instance.SelectAllWith(email_uzivatele, "Reklama na určitou částku");
             adverts.allAdvert = time;
             adverts.allAdvert2 = price;
             return View(adverts);
         }
```

View:

```
@model IList<SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models.DashboardModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}

<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <h2>Všechny reklamy na určitou dobu</h2>


        <table class="table-hover"  style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Název reklamy
                </th>
                <th>
                    Typ reklamy
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cena reklamy
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email uživatele
                </th>

                <th>
                    Datum začátku
                </th>
                <th>
                    Datum konce
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.nazev_reklamy
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.typ_reklamy
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.cena_reklamy
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.email_uzivatele
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.datumz
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.datumk
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <h2>Všechny reklamy na určitou částku</h2>


        <table class="table-hover" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Název reklamy
                </th>
                <th>
                    Typ reklamy
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cena reklamy
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email uživatele
                </th>


                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.nazev_reklamy
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.typ_reklamy
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.cena_reklamy
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.email_uzivatele
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

    </div>
</div>
```

But in view it is giving this error:

```
Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models.DashboardModel'
because 'SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models.DashboardModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

And in controller these two lines:

```
 adverts.allAdvert = time;
 adverts.allAdvert2 = price;
```

are giving me this error :

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SmartAdvertising.Entities.Advert>'
to 'SmartAdvertising.Entities.Advert'
```

Comment: Errors are clear. Properties in your model are not list types.

Comment: You're trying to assign a list of things to a property that accepts only a single thing.  And your view model isn't a list of anything, so of course you can't iterate over it.

Comment: But when i change in my viewmodel entities to list :                                              
        public List<Advert> allAdvert { get; set; }
        public List<Advert> allAdvert2 { get; set; }
it is stil giving me the same error in view: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models.DashboardModel' because 'SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models.DashboardModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties in model must be of type List:

```
public class DashboardModel
{
    public List<Advert> allAdvert { get; set; }
    public List<Advert> allAdvert2 { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally, you have to iterate over the properties of the model:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.allAdvert)
```

Comment: i changed to list but still it is giving me the same error in view: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models.DashboardModel' because 'SmartAdvertising.Backend.Models.DashboardModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: You have to iterate over the properties of the model. See the complete answer.